# ternary operator within .filter()

Tags: javascript

A simple example.

```
var evens= true;
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
var result = [];
  
if(evens){
  result = numbers.filter(num => num%2 === 0)
} else {
  result = numbers.filter(num => num%2 !== 0)
}
```

Is there a way to get something like  `result = numbers.filter(num => num%2 (evens) ? === : !==  0)` where depending on 'evens' to use equals or not equals to 0 within the .filter function? Is there a way to reuse same function to not have replication?

Comment: Do you ever expect to operate on any modulo other than 2? In this case, `!== 0` is the same as `=== 1`, which is much easier to generalize alongside `=== 0`

Comment: `const res = numbers.filter(num => evens ? num % 2 === 0 : num % 2 === 1);`

Comment: Why would you *want* to do that? You shouldn't be trying to write *less* code, if anything you should write *more* code to keep it readable and undestandable!

Comment: `numbers.filter(num => num % 2 !== +evens)` (Don't use this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just

`result = numbers.filter(num => !(num % 2) === evens)`

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think your code is fine and readable.

To better understand how to write higher-order functions for cases where they might be more appropriate, I'll answer your question as written:

In this case, `!== 0` is the same as `=== 1`, which is much easier to generalize alongside `=== 0`. We can write a function that returns a function output of the form `num => num%2 === SOMETHING`:

```
composeMod2Equals = target => num => num%2 === target
```

Then we can use it to build the necessary functions:

```
if(evens){
    result = numbers.filter(composeMod2Equals(0))
} else {
    result = numbers.filter(composeMod2Equals(1))
}
```

Or, since booleans will coerce to a `0`/`1` number, use `!evens` instead of the `if`:

```
result = numbers.filter(composeMod2Equals(+!evens))
```

This is much more generalized but vastly less readable! I'd suggest keeping what you have already.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
result = numbers.filter(num =>{
    let condition = evens ? num % 2 ===0 : num % 2 !== 0;
    return condition;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot use ternaries on operators, only on expressions. But that aside, you *should not try* stuff like this.

Ternaries serve a specific purpose, and this is not it.

Code should be readable, understandable and expandable. Your current code is just about okay but could be better.

For example:

```js
function filterByModulo(numbers, divisor, mod) {
    return numbers.filter(num => num % divisor === mod);
}
function filterEvens(numbers) {
    return filterByModulo(numbers, 2, 0);
}
function filterOdds(numbers) {
    return filterByModulo(numbers, 2, 1);
}
```

Now you can use `filterEvens()` or `filterOdds()` as appropriate, and this can be extended to any future modulo-based filtering you may need.